# Get Ids of Checked Checkboxes in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, formcollection

This is My View:

```
@foreach(var action in Model.Category.Actions) {
<div class="action" style="margin-right: 30px;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="@action.Id" name="actionChk" />
    <text>@action.Text</text>
</div>
  }
```

And html Dom is like the followings:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="17" name="actionChk">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="18" name="actionChk">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="19" name="actionChk">
```

So I need to get checked Ids. When I try to get values by form collection, that returned me an string array of `on` by length of checked checkboxes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection) {
    var actions = collection.GetValues("actionChk");
return View();
}
```

what is your suggestion?

Comment: Since the browser will post the input's name (actionChk), because they are all the same name you will get the array. Why not mangle the name to be actionChk17, actionChk18 etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should put the values in the `value` parameter

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="17" value="17" name="actionChk">
 <input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="18" value="18" name="actionChk">
 <input type="checkbox" class="chk-act" id="19" value="19" name="actionChk">
```

Then, from the controller, you should have an array of `Ids` named `actionChk`

Comment: Simple and useful answer.